# Spring-retry UniformrandomBackOff vs ExponentialRandomBackoff

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry, exponential-backoff

Spring retry provides a [UnifromRandomBackOff](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/backoff/UniformRandomBackOffPolicy.html). Is there any study on how it performs in practice compared to well-known [ExponentialRandomBackoff](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/backoff/ExponentialRandomBackOffPolicy.html)? Is there any guideline on which to be preferred?